# I am using the brightcove playlist. can you please guid me how can i get the video Id when video selected from the playlist

Tags: video.js, brightcove

Right now three videos are loaded into the playlist. i want to know when user select some video from the playlist i want to get the video Id of that selected video.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, can you provide some example on what are you doing? thanks

Comment: Is your player/playlist code custom, or is it being generated via Brightcove (BC) Cloud? If it's from the BC Cloud, then you should be able to get the playlist info from the mediaInfo object inside of the video player object.

Take a look at the API https://support.brightcove.com/guide-playlist-api